# JavaScript fixed length array on insert re-allocate item position

Tags: javascript

I have a fixed length array. The maximum item of the array will be the limit variable like as below.

```
var limit=3;

var list=[1,2];
```

My goal a is when a new item is inserted it will be like as behaviour.

```
add item => 8

[8,1,2]



add item => 5

[5,8,1]
```

How can I solve this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called LIFO (Last In, First Out) queue. You can try to implement similar logic as it is in function below. Here you add item at beginning of the array and pop last item from array if it's length is out of limited bound.

```
function addArrayItem(array, item, len) {
    array.unshift(item);
    if(array.length > len) {
        array.pop();
    }
}
```